# CodePage error while importing data from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I get the following warning on the OLEDB Source in the SSIS package.

> Warning   1   Validation warning. Data Flow Task:
>   {20582F6F-DD9C-45F5-8727-992F525E67DC}: Cannot retrieve the column
>   code page info from the OLE DB provider.  If the component supports
>   the "DefaultCodePage" property, the code page from that property will
>   be used.  Change the value of the property if the current string code
>   page values are incorrect.  If the component does not support the
>   property, the code page from the component's locale ID will be used.

After setting the AlwaysUseDefaultCoePage to true the warning disappears but 0 rows are transferred from source to destination. There is also no error shown.

**Update:** The oracle server uses the **US7ASCII** character set. I am unable to find the code page number for this character set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code page identifier for US-ASCII (7-bit) is **20127**

You can find the list of all code page identifiers in the following link.

[**Code Page Identifiers (MSDN)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Following link might also help you to find additional info with respect to your issue:

[**Error importing data from oracle database to an SQL database**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/dc1a61f2-1ab8-4ed3-b85c-db6481800b50/)