# LONG text in Oracle cut short by SSIS source?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, ssis

I am migrating a database from an Oracle database to an SQL Server 2008 R2 schema using SSIS. There is a column in one of the oracle tables with `long` text in it. In order to fit the desired schema I am using an SQL command in the OLEDB source which uses a number of joins to get the desired data.

On migrating instead of the whole `long` string only the first 100 characters are transferred from the source and the rest get trimmed. After I tried a query without any joins I was able to extract the whole text intact.

While running the query on Oracle client the proper result came out. Please suggest any direct way to rectify the problem? Currently I am using an SQL table temporarily to transfer the data before extracting data from Oracle database with a joinless query.

Comment: R u using the Code page for Oracle in your OLEDB source which is 20127.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188334/codepage-error-while-importing-data-from-oracle-to-sql-server-using-ssis

Comment: Although AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage property is true in this case, I am facing no such errors or warnings only the length of the string is cut short when using joins in the sql command.

Comment: Use `Advanced Editor` for `OLEDB Source` and manually change the length for the column. It seems weird that `with joins` the data is getting `truncated` .Can u post your oracle query.Try to placed `data viewer` just after your source and check whether you are getting the correct data or not

Comment: Even with `Data viewer` placed at the source ,you are able to see the data being `truncated` ?

Comment: Yes, in the previewed data also truncation is visible.

Comment: Do you see any Warning pertaining to `truncation` in SSIS ? At the most you can change the length for the column in `Advanced Editor`

Comment: I would stick with your "temporarily" design - in my experience it is best to keep the initial transfer between any two storage formats as simple as possible, to minimize the exposure to these obscure bugs in drivers etc. It usualy also runs quicker (end-to-end).  Also if you have SQL Server Enterprise edition it is worth getting the Attunity Drivers for Oracle - they seem much faster and less buggy.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to this that is basically an embellishment of what is written above.

I needed the joined data, and I didn't want to have to pull back "raw" copies of all the joined tables, so I pull in two sources: one a raw copy of the table with the `LONG` column using the table direct method, not an SQL command (filtered to only take the primary key and the relevant `LONG` column) - as mentioned above this preserves the complete contents of the long text. Then another source with all the joins and the `LONG` columns excluded (called "Metadata" below).

Then simply pass both sources individually through a `Sort`, and then feed these into a `Merge Join`, joining on the primary key column and selecting only the required columns.

[image: Diagram]